# CRM 2015 - 'Deactivate' button behavior on a Form

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

In CRM 2013, the 'Deactivate' button on a Form used to show the deactivate dialog and let the user choose which status reason to set. With CRM 2015, it looks like this behavior has changed. When I click the 'Deactivate' button on a form, it directly deactivates the record (to the default inactive status reason option).  However, clicking the deactivate button from a View shows the Dialog.

How can we change this behavior ?

Thanks

Rajesh

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that was a bug in at least one version of CRM. Try updating to the latest rollup.

Failing that report the issue to Microsoft for clarification on expected behaviour.